# Microsoft Exchange Server - (C# API) Retrieve all appointments for all users

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2013, microsoft-exchange

I've got to write some tool that will track meetings among the whole company. To do this I need to have the information on all appointments from all folders of all users. EWS API seems to only work with one user at the time and requires user credentials (did I miss something important here? ). Is there other options or a strategies to implement this approach?

P.S. I also found that there is OAuth that probably can help me with this task, but I didn't find any information whether it works the way I need it with Exchange Server 2013

Comment: Hi, did you already read something about [impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ?

Comment: Sure, but it seems to me that I should do It once again with more attention :) For some reason I didn't notice that there is an option to configure impersonation for all users in an organization. Thank you for advice. I'll investigate it.